# How to call Logic app from Asp.net core application on button click

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-logic-apps

I have scheduled an Azure Logic App to trigger an API method in my asp.net core web application.
But I want to trigger that logic app by clicking a button in my custom UI. So is there any examples or steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a request trigger "[When a HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres)", it will provide you a url, you can add this url to the button in UI(maybe in its "href" or you can use js to do it). When you click the UI button, it will trigger the logic app.